# Web root folder - www

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

`Visual Studio 2015 RC` has changed the project system to use `ASP.net 5` folder structure.  The change from previous version is the introduction of the `www` folder.

I am unable to use site root-relative paths (such as `/css/references.css`) when linking to external resources. I get "Failed to load resource" error.
Document-relative paths (`../css/references.css`) work.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reference.css" > **Fails**
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reference.css" > **Works**`
```

[image]

Is there a way to use site root-relative paths?

> **Description of web root for ASP.NET 5**
>
> The Web root of your application is the root location in your project from which HTTP requests are handled (ex. handling of static file requests). The Web root of an ASP.NET 5 application is configured using the “webroot” property in your project.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no.

Cordova apps do not stand up an HTTP server on the device to avoid both CORS issues and to ensure a low memory and CPU footprint. Instead it uses file paths and thus has no concept of a "web root".  Unfortunately the exact file path varies by platform out of necessity, so you will need to use relative paths.

Also, as a small side note, the file structure in Tools for Apache Cordova projects in VS 2015 RC is actually that of the [Cordova Command Line Interface,](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) not ASP.NET. This was done so you can use other command line tools with Cordova projects including the Cordova CLI itself.

Comment: Chuck,

Thanks for the quick and thorough response. 

Ryan Salva had mentioned the ASP.NET file structure in his ignite presentation:

`Getting Started with Cross-Platform Mobile Development with Apache Cordova
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK2704`

It would have been nice to create a project.json and modify the `{ "webroot":"" }`

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yeah the project system is related to the ASP.NET project system and inherits capabilities like filesystem mirroring, but it does not use ASP.NET itself.